# How can I set attribute disable to a display: none field

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to remove all my form elements which have `style=display:none` and I figure out to try giving them `attribute disable` so to be sure they wont be send in request to server? What is the way to handle that?

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: You could use [jQuery.remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove those items from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add this as a comment to the first answer from AmmarCSE, but not enough reputation points to do that yet. :-(

I think his snippet (`$(':hidden').attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('display', 'block');`) is likely not working because you put it in the submit event (per your comment) - so it's being executed after the form has been submitted. I would try putting it in a `$(document).ready(function{});` Note that if you put it in document ready, you may want to leave off the `.css('display', 'block')` part of the code if you want the elements to stay hidden.

Comment: Yes, this maybe what the OP wanted. @destructor, take a look at this answer

Comment: When I attached it to document.ready it breaks my whole site.

Comment: this is where we'll need some more context - do you have other hidden elements in your site that this is breaking?  could also be a syntax error in JS...  what does 'breaks my whole site' mean? (nothing shows up at all? everything is pink?)  If you can share some code behind this - ideally as a fiddle or codepen, I'm happy to help troubleshoot a bit more.

Comment: Yes, I have other hidden elements and I think this affects them too. By 'my site brokes' I mean..huh yeah css failed to load and a lot of Javascript errors are prompted. Currently I have this line `$('#parent-div-id').children(":input").prop("disabled", true); ` which works but I have to call it foreach field I want to disable in event. I'll give a try on jsfiddle, but my whole idea is to remove all display: none styled elements from my current from.

Comment: Maybe something like this will work:  `$('#form-id').find("input:hidden").prop("disabled", true);`  - or - you may also want to try using a class selector in your current snippet that's working (add the same class on all the elements you are currently calling individually with `#parent-div-id`)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':hidden').attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: I tried this in my `submit()` form event and values are still passing via url

Comment: can you replicate it in a fiddle?